# React Native Calendar - Date not showing

Tags: react-native-calendars

I am using react-native-calender plugin with bare minimum example. Strangely, Unable to see the dates on left column.

[image]

It was expected to look something like this.

[image]

Label showing 9 Mon is not coming.

Comment: how to use custom header. Could you provide your example code?

Answer (score 0):

For me, formatting the date to YYYY-MM-DD solves the problem.

```
const items = {
  '2022-10-04': [
    {
      "key": "200008",
      "value": "200040",
    }
  ],
  '2022-10-06': [
    {
      "key": "200008",
      "value": "200040",
    }
  ]
}
```